# "Горухща" — значение весьма странного слова

Tags: значение-слов, выбор-слов, история

У Игоря Николаевича Сухих есть статья *«Классное чтение: от горухщи до Гоголя».*

Что это за слово такое — ***горухща***?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***"Гороухща"*** ("гороушна", "гороуща", "гороуниа", "горухща") – самая древняя известная нам подлинная надпись на русском языке.
Она была обнаружена на глиняном крымском кувшине (корчаге, амфоре), найденном в 1949 году при раскопке кургана № 13 возле села Гнёздово под Смоленском.

В древнерусском языке звук, который мы сейчас произносим как "у", был иногда более долгим – "оу". Предпоследние две буквы написаны слитно и читать их можно по-разному: или **ХЩ** или **ШN** – в те отдаленные времена русскую букву "Н" писали как теперешнюю латинскую.
[**История цивилизации в Древней Руси (горухща)**](https://books.google.ee/books?id=IbTdCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT27&lpg=PT27&dq=%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%83%D1%85%D1%89%D0%B0&source=bl&ots=3-6E4rkMRo&sig=TyPG2EjoM36c-UwSbzu5Na35tdU&hl=et&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi-jcfp8oHVAhVMEJoKHYnjDSAQ6AEIJzAB#v=onepage&q=%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%83%D1%85%D1%89%D0%B0&f=false)

Надпись выполнена кириллицей и состоит из одного слова.
Д. А. Авдусин (археолог) и М. Н. Тихомиров (академик) толковали надпись так: ***гороухща*** – ***горчица***. Они предположили, что в амфоре-корчаге привезли на Русь горчицу или какие-нибудь другие пряности – например, перец, а затем тот, кто купил эту корчагу, чтобы не спутать ее с другими, процарапал на ней: "гороухща", как писали позднее: "доброе вино", "масло".
Языковед П. Я. Черных читал надпись ***гороушна*** – ***горчичные зерна***.
Г. Ф. Корзухина предположила также, что расположенные перед лигатурой буквы "ОУ" могли заменять существовавшие в те времена, но скоро исчезнувшие из нашего языка, носовые звуки – большой или малый "юс". В последнем случае можно читать что-то вроде "горюща" или "горяща" – ***горючее***.

Версий значений слова и версий появления крымского кувшина под Смоленском (в десятом веке!) - великое множество. Что-то из них можно посмотреть [**здесь**](https://www.e-reading.club/chapter.php/47305/3/Rabinovich_-_Sud%27by_veshcheii.html).
(М.Г.Рабинович, "Судьбы вещей", часть 4, "Гороухща", 1984)

Comment: Плюс - за ссылку.   *Самая древняя известная нам подлинная надпись на русском языке* - это неверно. Это неверно. Самая древняя из бесспорных - в лучшем случае. Да и то... "В 1952 г. Т. Арне высказал мысль, что гнездовская корчага не местного происхождения, а вывезена из Крыма или византийских владений и имела уже надпись" - (по моей ссылке).

Comment: Автор утверждения  "самая древняя известная нам подлинная русская надпись" - Михаил Григорьевич Рабинович — известный советский историк, археолог и этнограф, москвовед.  Доктор исторических наук (1963). Лауреат Государственной премии Российской Федерации (1993).

Comment: Да хоть Александр Македонский. Ссылку давайте и пишите, что по формулировке Рабиновича, ибо оспаривается. Это раз. И что толку-то, что Рабинович, если некорректное утверждение - два?!  Известны более ранние надписи в отношении которых ведется дискуссия. Они могут тоже оказаться подлинными. Может, историки по-своему понимаю "подлинность", но нормальные люди не смешивают подлинность и доказательства подлинности.

Answer (score 2):

+Это действительно странное слово. Встречается якобы единственный раз как надпись на глиняном сосуде, конца первого тысячелетия, вероятно - для пряностей. По Сухих считается самой древней из бесспорных сохранившихся русских надписей (всякие якобы предшествующие "черты и резы" и рунические надписи - дискуссионны.

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BD%D1%91%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C

Вот авторское.

> Русская письменность начинается с неразборчивой надписи на разбитом
>   глиняном сосуде (он был найден под Смоленском только в 1949 году),
>   которая читается то как горухща, то как – как горушна, то как горунща,
>   а переводится чаще всего как горчица. Археологи датируют ее серединой
>   X века. От этой надписи до первой известной русской книги, так
>   называемого Остромирова Евангелия (1056–1057), – всего сто лет, а до
>   великого «Слова о полку Игореве» – около двух веков. По историческим
>   меркам русская литература родилась почти мгновенно.

[ссылка](http://velib.com/read_book/sukhikh_igor_nikolaevich/russkaja_literatura_dlja_vsekh_klassnoe_chtenie_ot_slova_o_polku_igoreve_do_lermontova/literatura_ot_gorukhshhi_do_bednojj_lizy/)

Вообще-то автору стоило бы более подробно раскрыть в тексте значение далеко не общеизвестного слова, вынесенного им в заголовок. То, что он этого не сделал, - не в плюс его труду.

=================

Вообще об этом сосуде мало сведений. Вот единственно более или менее понятное.

> Нечто подобное утверждал тогда же и Д. А. Авдусин: славянскую
>   принадлежность погребенного в ладье в кургане 13, по мнению автора,
>   подтверждала и славянская надпись «Горухща» — горчица, процарапанная
>   на южнорусской амфоре, найденной там же. Исследователь не замечал, что
>   двумя страницами ранее он указывал, что надпись сделана «до ее
>   транспортировки на Смоленщину» т. е. на юге, и для покупателя ее в
>   Смоленске (Гнездове) была уже не так важна, а следовательно, в
>   «доказательствах» участвовать не может (Авдусин Д. А. Отчет о
>   раскопках гнездовских курганов в 1949 г. — МИСО, Смоленск, 1952, вып.
>   1, с. 328, ср. с. 319).

http://annales.info/rus/alekseev/smol10.htm

С другой стороны встречваются косвенные указание на существование на Смоленщине некоего города с названием Горухщи (сама форма топонима вполне употребительна в тех местах). Недостоверно, но объясняет, в частности, то, что "Горухщи" пишут с заглавной.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! А то нигде не получалось отыскать...

Answer (score 1):

Не полноценный ответ, но дополнительная информация. В этих статьях из словаря ЦСРЯ горчица — растение, которое нам не известно, и — библейский символ.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, Горухща, значение очевидно каждому болгарину. Горух(щ)а (лат. название Lepidium campestre) - это растение, которое может быть использовано как для пищи, так и как специя с вкусом перца. Оно также является травой, которая лечит некоторые заболевания, связанные с пищеварением. В данном случае, очевидно, она была хранена как приправа, специя, поскольку перец еще не появился в Европе из Индии, того времени.
А во вторих — это именно вкус черного перца, который грорячий, а токово болгарское слово для горячий, жигучий «горещо» но без Х, но известно что например паразитно е Х доволно часто втречается в украинских говорах, а болгар как известно выходцы из Восточной Украиной и Южной России. У вас есть наблюдение за языками, как они развивались во времени, особенно славянские. Вот хороший пример того, как одно слово для названия растения стало двумя, или растения взяло свое название от слова горячий, которое по-староболгарски вероятно произносилось - горУ(е)Хщо. Староболгарский язык изучают в школе в Болгарии, и он полон таких слов, которые сегодня болгарам трудно произносить и были гласние звуки которие произносили по разному как  Е, У, Ъ в разхых регионах Болгарий, даже и сегодня. Вот пример с слово чешма ( водный кран ), она на разние говора болгарий произносится как - чушмъ, чишма, чешмъ, чишмъ, или живот (жизн) - жувот, жевот и т.д.
А вообще, хорошо знаете, славянские языки трудны для других народов именно из-за их фонетики и специфических звуков щ, ж (дж), ч, у, а в то время тоже было много носовок (он), (ан), (ен) :)
Также вам хорошо известна причина создания славянской азбуки именно потому, что воспроизвести звуки старославянских языков, особенно древнеболгарского, с греческим и латынью было сложно. Кириллический алфавит также был создан в Плиске, где были найдены и продолжают находить древнейшие кириллические надписи. Недавно рядом с крепостью, находившейся на границе с Византией, нашли свинцовый амулет с кирилических цитатами из Евангелия от начало 10 ого века. Из Плиски алфавит вместе со старославянским, ставшим государственным языком в первом Болгарском царстве, стал распространяться по всем окрестным славянским народам и в свою очередь стал использоваться в административных целях и торговле. Просто напомню и что Первое Болгарское царство не имеет ничего общего с нынешней Болгарией, оно занимало огромную территорию и простиралось от сегодняшней Греции до западной Украины и Венгрии, охватывая всю Сербию и Северную Македонию, тоже простиралось на западе до Адриатическим морем и Хорватией. Вы сами видите, что это царство в период своего расцвета граничило с территорией древней Руси и имело всевозможный обмен - торговый, культурный, религиозный, даже военный. И к сожелению для его разспад причина была война с Русю когда Светослав претендовал директно для болгарский престол... Тоже можно напомнить, что такие имена, как Владимир и Борис, впервые упоминаются как имена болгарских царей. т.е. лингвистически, культурно и этнически Болгария и древняя Русь были гораздо более тесно связаны, и на мой взгляд это довольно недооценено русскими учеными, думаю кроме Дмитрия Лихачева. Могу привести пример с другой надписью найдена на Руси, которая является загадкой для русских лингвистов, но чрезвычайно проста для понимания болгарами: "и замке келея врата, ке лея" - и дверь замковой кельи буду отлить ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uzzjnpPmEDQ ).